# Does the OData protocol provide a way to transform an array of objects to an array of raw values?

Tags: rest, odata

Is there a way specify in an OData query that instead of certain name/value pairs being returned, a raw array should be returned instead? For example, if I have an OData query that results in the following:

```json
{
  "@odata.context": "http://blah.org/MyService/$metadata#People",
  "value": [
    {
      "Name": "Joe Smith",
      "Age": 55,
      "Employers": [
        {
          "Name": "Acme",
          "StartDate": "1/1/1990"
        },
        {
          "Name": "Enron",
          "StartDate": "1/1/1995"
        },
        {
          "Name": "Amazon",
          "StartDate": "1/1/1999"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "Jane Doe",
      "Age": 30,
      "Employers": [
        {
          "Name": "Joe's Crab Shack",
          "StartDate": "1/1/2007"
        },
        {
          "Name": "TGI Fridays",
          "StartDate": "1/1/2010"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there anything I can add to the query to instead get back:

```json
{
  "@odata.context": "http://blah.org/MyService/$metadata#People",
  "value": [
    {
      "Name": "Joe Smith",
      "Age": 55,
      "Employers": [
        [ "Acme", "1/1/1990" ],
        [ "Enron", "1/1/1995" ],
        [ "Amazon", "1/1/1999" ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "Jane Doe",
      "Age": 30,
      "Employers": [
        [ "Joe's Crab Shack", "1/1/2007" ],
        [ "TGI Fridays", "1/1/2010" ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

While I could obviously do the transformation client side, in my use case the field names are very large compared to the data, and I would rather not transmit all those names over the wire nor spend the CPU cycles on the client doing the transformation. Before I come up with my own custom parameters to indicate that the format should be as I desire, I wanted to check if there wasn't already a standardized way to do so.

Comment: In your desired output you make arrays different types of values. This is generally not something I would do. In my opinion it would hurt your API.

It will result in less data sent, yes. However it will also result in a less clear API in which the clients will have to make assumptions (The first field of an array under in the Employers Array should be the name, if it does not look like a date ). 

Next to that it makes it harder to work with, a client cannot just retrieve the name or StartDate of an Employer by specifically asking for it.

Comment: Agreed; keep in mind that I'm looking for a way to explicitly request this format from a standard OData API using a query in order to *not* make this format part of my API itself, i.e. the same client that determines this format would be the one interpreting the results.

FWIW, my actual use case consists of X,Y values for a chart; instead of an array of objects like {timestamp: 12345, value: 77}, I'd like to receive an array of tuples like [12345,77].

Comment: Did you ever find a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OData provides several options to control the amount of data and metadata to be included in the response.

In OData **v4**, you can add `odata.metadata=minimal` to the `Accept` header parameters (check the documentation [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.0/cs01/odata-json-format-v4.0-cs01.html#_Toc365464675)). This is the default behaviour but even with this, it will still include the field names in the response and for a good reason.

I can see why you want to send only the values without the fields name but keep in mind that this will change the semantic meaning of the response structure. It will make it less intuitive to deal with as a json record on the client side.

So to answer your question,  The answer is 'NO',

Other options to minimize the response size:

You can use the **$value** OData option to gets the raw value of a single property.
Check this example:
[services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Categories(1)/Products(1)/Supplier/Address/City/$value](http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Categories(1)/Products(1)/Supplier/Address/City/$value)

You can also use the **$select** option to cherry pick only the fields you need by selecting a subset of properties to include in the response

Comment: Thanks; unfortunately (afaik) the $value keyword only works with single values, whereas I am looking for something that can transform multiple values in an array; basically the equivalent of `result.map(obj => [obj.Name, obj.StartDate])`.

Comment: You are right. It will only work for a single value. I dug deeper into the OData documentation and found the odata.metadata=minimal format parameter. It also suggests that the answer for your question is 'NO' and for a good reason as I am describing in my revised answer

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. As I mentioned in my response to another comment, I'm not too concerned about the response format being non-intuitive, as it would be the client specifying the format of what is returned; the default response would still be standard.